# What if I have burnt my atmega328p?

Tags: avrdude, isp

Actually I am facing a big problem while programming my atmega328p using an arduino uno as ISP. 
I followed a video on youtube  "Arduino as ISP" by Notes and Volts. Which look doing the same steps that the majority followed. For the blinking LED sketch the µC worked very well and it did not show any troubles. 
So I  decided to carry on , and at this point I needed to upload a new program but this i wanted to upload my program using "avrdude" command line because my code was written with MikroC pro for avr, and here is the command line :

`"avrdude -p atmega328p -b 19200 -C arduino -P COM7 -U lfuse:w:0xf7:m -U 
 hfuse:w:0xc9:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m -U flash:w:LED.hex:i "`

But unfortunately it did not work well and I have got the following error :

`avrdude : invalid byte value <ff> specified for immediate mode 
 avrdude : write to file 'ff' failed 
 avrdude : safemode : Fuses OK`

Seeing that error paniced me , that's why I decided to retry the programmation with an arduino sketch and then happened the big issue when the arduino generate an error message about finding a bad microcontroller [error about the device signature] [[image: PIC]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LFor.png).
My last try to find out if I ruined my µC is with switching the µCs; the arduino original and the one that I had to program and unfortunately It was not a good result : 
"avrdude : stk500_recv() : programmer is not responding 
 avrdude : stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10 : not in sync : resp=0x85"  [image: PIC]
Looking for more than day on the internet and I could not find a valid solution , except the possibility that I really BURNT my µC and I have to buy another one. And this is specifically why I am asking for your help; I need  to know if SO could figure this trouble out.Otherwise, could somebode confirm to me that there is no hope with my µC and it's gone and I have to stop trying to make it works . 
Thank you 
Regards

Comment: Without looking into the exact fuses that you set, there are a few that can cause the chip to not take new programming: If you set it to use an external clock crystal, you then need to have that external clock crystal connected to the chip in order to reprogram it. Or if you set the RESET pin as an output, you need a high voltage programmer to reprogram it. Oh, by the way, have you tried to "write bootloader" in the Arduino UI? If you have overwritten the bootloader it probably won't let you reprogram the chip until you've uploaded the bootloader again.

Comment: I did connect an external clock crystal of 16Mhz with its two 22pF capacitors. what do you mean by high voltage programmer 
I have already burnt the bootloader but in all casses using the µC (that should be programmed) on the ardiono board does not allow me to upload any sketch even for burning the bootloader

Comment: Swapping the ICs would seem to mean you'd be trying to use the misprogrammed target chip as an ISP programmer; that of course won't work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no I did not try to use the misprogrammed target as an ISP programmer, I tried only to upload a simple blink sketch to it to discover if it still working or not

Comment: You can't use a misprogrammed IC in an Arduino as it won't have a valid bootloader (on the ATmega series, ISP can only erase the whole chip, so any attempt to ISP that does not install a working one means there will be no bootloader)

Comment: @ChrisStratton ook I see what you mean now ; I did not know this information before thank you for this. 
So I guess that I have to forget about this chip and buy a new one, Right??

Comment: With a working ISP setup and external clock you should be able to fix it, unless you set the reset disable fuse in which case you need a high voltage programmer.  But getting a new one may be simplest.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Would you please tell me how to fix it using a working ISP and external clock? it is not because I do not want to buy a new one but I am afraid to face the same errors even with a new one

Answer (score 2):

Trying your fuse settings on an
[AVR fuse calculator](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/) shows that you
have selected an “external full-swing crystal” as the clock source.
Now your ATmega won't work unless you connect it to an external crystal.
Or you could try just sending a square wave into the XTAL1 pin. *Then*
you can try to reprogram it.

Comment: it's already connected to an external crystal. And when I tried to reprogram it, the arduino software generate an error about selecting a bad µC

Answer (score 2):

after two days of searching on internet, I decided to just reburn the bootloader again on my target µC to discover if it's really burned or not. 
SO, I guess it was not damaged because I was able to burn the bootloader and upload the blink led  sketch successfully.

Comment: The first part of this could be an answer of the "the problem must have been elsewhere" sort; but the second part where you ask a question is not allowed in an answer, and must be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> What if I have burnt my atmega328p?

get a new one.

> Otherwise, could somebode confirm to me that there is no hope with my µC and it's gone and I have to stop trying to make it works .

based on the information you have provided, no one can tell definitively. you could have changed the fuse settings, or your 2nd chip didn't have the bootloader, or bad connection, ....

a better approach is to get a separate programmer - usbasp for low prices, or dragon (older debugger with hv programming capability) and go from there.

Comment: Actually, I am using the arduino as an ISP  programmer because it was decreed by the company I am working for that's why the possibility of using a separate programmer is not allowed .